# HTML CSS design problems

Tags: html, css

I'm designing an HTML & CSS page both for printing and web.
While I have no problems for printing, I'm experiencing troubles in web version:

1. I have some divs which can display blank row. In fixed dimensions (printing) the divs show correctly, while when I'm using percentages to divide page, nothing is showed because the box seems collapsed. Is there a way to fix this?
2. It seems not possible to draw an "optimized" website using only percentages and divs, or better: **I CAN'T SEE HOW TO DO IT**. So what is the best practice to draw a fully resizable web page with pictures inside?

If you need some extra informations on how about the page should be done let me know, I'll update the question. Also: since "developing" web pages is not my favourite duty, I might mispelled some terms, feel free to update the question, I would appreciate that.

```css
address
{
  font-size: 12pt;
}
body
{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
/**********************************************************************
* CSS: Classi                                                        *
**********************************************************************/
div.PieDiPagina
{
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.4%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 98.5%;
}
/**********************************************************************
* CSS: Id                                                           *
**********************************************************************/
#ColonnaDestra
{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  width: 24%;
}
#ColonnaSinistra
{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  width: 74%;
}
#TestataSinistra
{
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
}
#LogoSixton
{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#Pagina
{
  float: left;
}
#T1
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 47%;
}
#T1A
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 47%;
}
#V1
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 47%;
}
#V1A
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 47%;
}
#T3
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 47%;
}
#T4
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 47%;
}
#V3
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 47%;
}
#V4
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 47%;
}
#T6
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 60%;
}
#T7
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 34%;
}
#V6
{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  width: 62%;
}
#V6IMG
{
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#V7
{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 36%;
}
#V7IMG
{
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#T20
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 15%;
}
#V20
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 50%;
}
#T19
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 26%;
}
#T212223
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 15%;
}
#V212223
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 50%;
}
#V19
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 26%;
}
#T24
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 15%;
}
#V24
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 50%;
}
#T11
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 26%;
}
#T2529
{
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0.2%;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  width: 98.5%;
}
#T2529_Inner
{
  float: left;
  width: 71%;
}
#V11
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.6%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 26%;
}
#V11Img
{
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#T25
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.4%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 22.0%;
}
#V25
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.8%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 71.8%;
}
#T26
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.4%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 22.0%;
}
#V26
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 0.8%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 71.8%;
}
#T27
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.4%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 22.0%;
}
#V27
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 0.8%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom:0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 71.8%;
}
#T28
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.4%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 22.0%;
}
#V28
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 0.8%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 71.8%;
}
#T29
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.4%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 22.0%;
}
#V29
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 0.8%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 71.8%;
}
#T15
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.4%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 22.0%;
}
#V15
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.8%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 21.5%;
}
#T16
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.4%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 22.0%;
}
#V16
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.8%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 21.5%;
}
#T17
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.4%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 68.8%;
}
#T14
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.4%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 27%;
}
#V17
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.4%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 69.8%;
}
#V17Img
{
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#V14
{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0.4%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 27%;
}
#V14Img
{
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#T18
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.4%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 97.5%;
}
#V18
{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.4%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 97.5%;
}
#V18Img
{
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#Logo
{
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
#Img
{
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#CorrettorePiePagina
{
  background-color: #FEDE93;
  float: left;
}
#IndirizzoMaspica
{
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 9.5%;
  width: 59.5%;
}
#SchedaTecnica
{
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-style: italic;
}
#TestataDestra
{
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#Bandiera
{
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  width: 100%;
}
#BandieraImg
{
  float: right;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#MadeInItaly
{
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 98%;
  padding: 1%;
}
#T2
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-top: 41.9%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V2
{
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  padding: 3%;
  width: 98%;
}
#T5
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V5
{
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V5Img
{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#T27Bis
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V8
{
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V8Img
{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#T9
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V9
{
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V9Img
{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#T10
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V10
{
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V10Img
{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#T12
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V12
{
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V12Img
{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#T13
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.1%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V13
{
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  width: 98%;
}
#V13Img
{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#DataStampa
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 89%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="Pagina">
  <div id="ColonnaSinistra">
    <div id="TestataSinistra">
      <img id="Logo" src="Box Logo Testata/Logo Testata.jpg" alt="Mark">
    </div>
    <div id="T1">Mod</div>
    <div id="T1A">Lin</div>
    <div id="V1">MyMod</div>
    <div id="V1A"></div><!-- Blank ROW COLLAPSED-->
    <div id="T3">Cod</div>
    <div id="T4">Prot</div>
    <div id="V3">Infos...</div>
    <div id="V4">Infos...</div>
    <div id="T6">Anteprima</div>
    <div id="T7">Infos...</div>
    <div id="V6">
      <img id="V6IMG" src="FotoCodArt/img.jpg" alt="Articolo">
    </div>
    <div id="V7">
      <img id="V7IMG" src="FotoSuola/Img.jpg" alt="Suola">
    </div>
    <div id="T20">Tip</div>
    <div id="V20">Infos...</div>
    <div id="T19">Settori di Util.</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
      <div id="T212223">Tom</div>
      <div id="V212223">Infos...</div>
      <div id="V19">Infos...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="T24">Fod</div>
    <div id="V24">Infos...</div>
    <div id="T11">SRC</div>
    <div id="T2529">
      <div id="T2529_Inner">
        <div id="T25">FodAntisciv.</div>
        <div id="V25">Infos...</div>
        <div id="T26">Suo</div>
        <div id="V26">Infos...</div>
        <div id="T27">Suo</div>
        <div id="V27">Infos...</div>
        <div id="T28">Punt</div>
        <div id="V28">Infos...</div>
        <div id="T29">AP</div>
        <div id="V29">Infos...</div>
        <div id="T15">Tag</div>
        <div id="V15">Infos...</div>
        <div id="T16">Peso gr.</div>
        <div id="V16">540</div>
      </div>
      <div id="V11">
        <img id="V11Img" src="FotoSrc/img.jpg" alt="SRC">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="T17">Caratteristiche</div>
    <div id="T14">Antistaticit&agrave;</div>
    <div id="V17">
      <img id="V17Img" src="FotoLogo/img.jpg" alt="Caratteristiche">
    </div>
    <div id="V14">
      <img id="V14Img" src="FotoESDWED/img.jpg" alt="Antistatico">
    </div>
    <div id="T18">Pittogrammi</div>
    <div id="V18">
      <img id="V18Img" src="FotoIcona/img.jpg" alt="Pittogrammi">
    </div>
    <div class="PieDiPagina">
      <div id="LogoMaspica">
        <img id="Head" src="Box Logo Piede/img.jpg" alt="Maspica">
      </div>
      <div id="CorrettorePiePagina">     </div>
      <div id="Address">
        <address>Infos</address>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="PieDiPagina">
      <p id="SchedaTecnica">Scheda Tecnica</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ColonnaDestra">
    <div id="TestataDestra">
      <div id="Bandiera">
        <img id="BandieraImg" src="Bandierine/ita_1.jpg" alt="ITA">
      </div>
      <div id="MadeInItaly">MADE IN ITALY</div>
    </div>
    <div id="T2">Standard</div>
    <div id="V2">Standard</div>
    <div id="T5">Disponibilit&agrave; a Magazzino</div>
    <div id="V5">
      <img id="V5Img" src="FotoMagazzino/mag.jpg" alt="Disponibilità">
    </div>
    <div id="T27Bis">Infos...</div>
    <div id="V8">
      <img id="V8Img" src="FotoDescSuola/Img.jpg" alt="Descr">
    </div>
    <div id="T9">Suo.</div>
    <div id="V9">
      <img id="V9Img" src="FotoSuoletta/img.jpg" alt="Descr">
    </div>
    <div id="T10">Prot</div>
    <div id="V10">
      <img id="V10Img" src="FotoPuntale/Img.jpg" alt="Descr">
    </div>
    <div id="T12">Plus</div>
    <div id="V12">
      <img id="V12Img" src="FotoStabilActive/Img.jpg" alt="Descr">
    </div>
    <div id="T13">Plus</div>
    <div id="V13">
      <img id="V13Img" src="FotoDynamicControl/Img.jpg" alt="Descr">
    </div>
    <div id="PieDiPagina">
      <p id="DataStampa">22 Dicembre 2015</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely we need extra information buddy.. :) Post some code to replicate.. :)

Comment: Add HTML and CSS. Are you using media queries for print and web designs?

Comment: Would be nice to see some code? If you are using percentages and also floating, did you forget clear:both perhaps? In any case, some code would be of help

Comment: Will try to post some code. @Justinas No, the page is plain old html and formatted with CSS and divs.

Comment: Can you add code in Jsfiddle?

Comment: @DineshKanivu I'll try. Meanwhile added all code in here.

Comment: Wow... That might be some of the worst html/CSS I've ever seen written. You might want to learn how to use classes.

Comment: @SeanStopnik Not much time to learn it. Alternatives to HTML were worst, any fast link?

Comment: Plz remove your relative link and add absolute link

Comment: All this floating and not a single clear, that can't be right. Anyway, for the collapsing divs, just give all divs a `min-height` and they won't collapse.

Comment: The real problem though is with the widths in percentages. If you want a responsive website (that displays nicely on narrow screens) that won't come out well. The main purpose of the site is to display the information, not to scale itself beautifully to the screen. One solution, since you're using floats anyway, is to give the relevant divs a `min-width` in em corresponding to the width you expect the content to be.

Comment: Already get the problem of clear. What if I don't know the min height?